# d3 v4 error: "Unexpected value parsing width attribute." in grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a d3 (version 4) grouped bar chart with my own data, based on [Mike Bostock's great example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051). I had to change all d3 v3 outdated functions to the new v4 ones (e.g. `d3.scale.ordinal` -> `d3.scaleOrdinal`) but then I got errors relating to the 'width' and 'x' attributes of the rect bars:

- 'Unexpected value 0,0,900 parsing width attribute.'
- 'Unexpected value 0,900 parsing x attribute.'

here is the relevant part of the code:

```
var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, width])
        .round(true);

var x1 = d3.scaleOrdinal();

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
        .scale(x0);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(y);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("myData.csv", function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;

      var yearNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Unit"; });

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.years = yearNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });

      });


 x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Unit; }));
 x1.domain(yearNames).range([0, x0.range()]);
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.years, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

 svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

 svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Population");

 var unit = svg.selectAll(".unit")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "unit")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Unit) + ",0)"; });

 unit.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d) { return d.years; })
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("width", x1.range())
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

   });
```

and here is the csv data:

```
Unit,2012,2013
Comp,54.13809524,52.25
Edu,20.39642857,18.75
Bus,16.3,18.5
SoW,16.08,7
Pharm,45,59
Agr,150.3,122.51
Soc,105.2,112.72
Nat,264.86,277.73
Hum,61.73174603,52.91
Law,14.5,22.33
Dent,27.5,11.5
Med,149.1,147.33
Vet,15,19
Jew,1,0.25
Bra,2.5,4
```

Comment: Debug your code. Narrow down where the error occurs.

Comment: What does your data look like?  There's nothing in your linked example with `Unit`?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thanks for the comment. the error is probably in the variable x1.domain and .range. I just can't figure out what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your problems come from an incorrect usage of `.range()`.  For example here:

```
x1.domain(yearNames).range([0, x0.range()]);
```

and here:

```
.attr("width", x1.range())
```

`.range` return an array, which is not what you want.

Further, you probably don't want `x1` to be a `scaleOrdinal` but rather a `scaleBand`.  I'd set it up like this:

```
  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.Unit;
  }));

  // set a sane bar width
  var barWidth = x0.bandwidth() / yearNames.length,
      barPadding = barWidth * 0.3;

  // set up x1 as a scaleBand with padding
  x1.domain(yearNames).range([barPadding , x0.bandwidth() - barPadding]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d.years, function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });
  })]);
```

[Running code here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/cCmd4YTwdSUAYpA0o7fe?p=preview)

Comment: thank you very much! I spent the entire weekend trying to figure out what causes the errors...